# Angular 6 - call multiple APIs synchronously

Tags: api, asynchronous, angular6

I have a simple function that call an API to get all categories of story. The response simply like this:

```
{"page":1,"pageSize":1,"totalRecords":39,"nextPageUrl":"http://dkm.services/api/story/categories?SiteId=1c0ad0e3-8c70-4a0c-9dd1-3285d0b243f2&Page=2&PageSize=10","items":[{"id":"96c9219a-b1a1-4dc5-9dbc-021720d71ab0","name":"Đông Phương","url":"http://truyenfull.vn/the-loai/dong-phuong/"}]}
```

Now I need to follow the `nextPageUrl` property to invoke the next call until all category are obtained (`nextPageUrl` = null)
The function will return an array of category, then it will be called in another component in my app.

How can I chain this multiple calls?

Thank you all.

Comment: Promises? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining

Comment: yes I can use promise only if I know exactly how many calls I need to invoke, but in my case I don't. I only know what is the current api's url and what is the next (returned from the previous response)

Answer (score 1):

You need recursive promise, something like this ...

```
function getCategories(nextPageUrl, categories) {
  return getCategoriesService(nextPageUrl)
    .then((res) => {
      if(res.nextPageUrl) {
        categories.push(res.categories)
        return getCategories(res.nextPageUrl, categories);
      } 
    });
}
```